# Include js file in Ajax XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm using Ajax and code which is described below. I want to include .js file in Ajax XMLHttpRequest. Does anybody know how to do that?

For example:
I have code below:

```
function getXMLHttp()
{
  var xmlHttp

  try
  {
    //Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    //Internet Explorer
    try
    {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      try
      {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!")
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xmlHttp;
}

function MakeRequest(id)
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", "updatesite.admin.php?id="+id, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function HandleResponse(response)
{
    document.getElementById('Vsebina').innerHTML = response;
}
```

When program call function MakeRequest(id) then i want to also executed some .js file.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: By "I want to include .js file in Ajax XMLHttpRequest." do you mean "I want to add JS to the page using `innerHTML` and have it execute"? The XMLHttpRequest seems to be something of a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

You could always put this code in your function to cause a script to be loaded and executed...

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "http://location-of-script.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Here's a complete example. These two files just need to be in the same folder on the server.

This is hello.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit()
{
  var scr = document.createElement('script');
  scr.type = "text/javascript";
  scr.src = "hello.js";
  document.body.appendChild(scr);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="hello" onclick="doit();">
</body>
</html>
```

And this is hello.js:

```
alert("helloooo!!");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this not help.

Comment: yeah, tested it in a more complete example just to make sure I hadn't dropped any bits on the floor.